# Is there a Latin 'studiare'?

Tags: verbs, language-evolution, spelling

The Latin verb for studying is *studere*, but a number of [descendants](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/studeo#Descendants) look as if they came from *studiare*.
These include the Italian 'studiare', French 'étudier', and the Spanish 'estudiar'.

Was there ever a Latin verb *studiare*?
If yes, was it interchangeable with *studere* and do we know how it came about?
(I could imagine *studiare* being derived from *studium* or arising from changes in inflected forms like *studeo > studio*.)
If no, does something else explain the abundant *-i-* in the descendants?

Answer (score 4):

I was wondering if the verb *studiare was classified into the 1st conjugation in non-Classical Latin on the basis of being transformed into a denominal verb (cf. *studium* > *studiare). NB: *studium* is formed on the basis of *studere* and not the other way around. 
This proposal/hypothesis is made on the basis that 1st conjugation is the one where **more** (but not all, of course) denominal verbs are found. I've not checked it out but at first sight it seems true. Do you share this intuition?

Comment: Wouldn't that lead to *_studīre_, not *_studiāre_?

Comment: Oh, you're right! So the explanation must be another one. I'll think about it.

Comment: Here you have another explanation (cf. supra). What do you think?